# Uploading multi-line .txt file with gdata gives 503 error

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have code that will upload a single-line .txt file to my Google Drive using gdata.  Same file, but with newline characters will not upload and gives:

```
gdata.client.RequestError: Server responded with: 503,
```

Remove the newline characters, and it goes through just fine.  Any idea how to fix this?

Edited to add working example:

```
import sys 
import time 
import os.path
import atom.data
import gdata.client, gdata.docs.client, gdata.docs.data
import urllib2

class GoogleDriveFileUpload:

    def __init__(self, fileName, targetFolder, username, password, ftype='txt'):

        self.fileName = fileName
        self.targetFolder = targetFolder
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.file_type = self.cvtFileType(ftype)


    def cvtFileType(self, ftype):
        if ftype == 'jpg':
            file_type = 'image/jpeg'
        elif ftype == 'kml':
            file_type = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
        elif ftype == 'txt':
            file_type = 'text/plain'
        elif ftype == 'csv':
            file_type = 'text/csv'
        elif ftype == 'mpg':
            file_type = 'audio/mpeg'
        elif ftype == 'mp4':
            file_type = 'video/mp4'

        return file_type

    def changeFile(self, fileName, ftype = 'txt'):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.file_type = cvtFileType(ftype)
        self.file_size = os.path.getsize(fhandle.name)

    def changeTarget(self, targetFolder):
        self.targetFolder = targetFolder

    def upload(self):
        #Start the Google Drive Login
        docsclient = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='GausLabAnalysis')

        # Get a list of all available resources (GetAllResources() requires >= gdata-2.0.15)
        # print 'Logging in...',
        try:
            docsclient.ClientLogin(self.username, self.password, docsclient.source);
        except (gdata.client.BadAuthentication, gdata.client.Error), e:
            sys.exit('Unknown Error: ' + str(e))
        except:
            sys.exit('Login Error. Check username/password credentials.')
        # print 'Success!'

        # The default root collection URI
        uri = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full'
        # Get a list of all available resources (GetAllResources() requires >= gdata-2.0.15)
        # print 'Fetching Collection/Directory ID...',
        try:
           resources = docsclient.GetAllResources(uri='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder?title=' + self.targetFolder + '&title-exact=true')
        except:
           sys.exit('ERROR: Unable to retrieve resources')
        # If no matching resources were found
        if not resources:
           sys.exit('Error: The collection "' + self.targetFolder + '" was not found.')
        # Set the collection URI
        uri = resources[0].get_resumable_create_media_link().href
        # print 'Success!'
        # Make sure Google doesn't try to do any conversion on the upload (e.g. convert images to documents)
        uri += '?convert=false'


        fhandle = open(self.fileName)
        self.file_size = os.path.getsize(fhandle.name)
        print 'Uploading ', self.fileName,'....' 
        # Create an uploader object and upload the file
        uploader = gdata.client.ResumableUploader(docsclient, fhandle, self.file_type, self.file_size, chunk_size=262144, desired_class=gdata.data.GDEntry)
        new_entry = uploader.UploadFile(uri, entry=gdata.data.GDEntry(title=atom.data.Title(text=os.path.basename(fhandle.name))))
        # print 'Success!',
        print 'File ' + self.fileName + ' uploaded to ' + self.targetFolder + ' at ' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y ", time.localtime()) + '.'


def internet_on():
    try:
        response=urllib2.urlopen('http://74.125.228.100', timeout=5)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def main():
    gdoc = GoogleDriveFileUpload('...\HelloWorld.txt', 'GoogleDriveFolderName', 'username', 'password') 
    if internet_on():
        gdoc.upload()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   main()
```

This works when HelloWorld.txt is:

```
Hello World!
```

but fails with the 503 error when the same file is:

```
Hello
World!
```

Only difference is a newline character put in with Notepad.  Same response when writing the file using '\n' rather than '\r\n'.

Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you include a more complete code sample? Especially useful would be seeing the gdata call you're using to do the upload.

Comment: Of course.  Code added.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself.  I went through the whole routine of setting up things with the new API, but that makes you go through a separate Drive account and then share the file rather than upload it directly (from what I can get working).  Good for an app, but not for me.

Couldn't get things to work with the ResumableUploader class, but CreateResource seems to do the job just fine.

Solution is to remove the two lines after

```
# Create an uploader object and upload the file
```

in the code above and add

```
    mS = gdata.data.MediaSource(content_type = gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES[self.ftype.upper()])
    mS.SetFileHandle(self.fileName, self.file_type)
    doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='file', title=os.path.basename(self.fileName))
    doc = docsclient.CreateResource(doc, media=mS, create_uri = uri)
```

That does it!